# How to handle json list in Spring?

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

i want to send all checkbox ids and checked parameter(1 or 0) as json list to server.I tried and googled many times but couldn't get any result.I get syntatically wrong error

my java code:

```
@Autowired
 ParamService paramService;

 @RequestMapping(value = "/refresh", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json", consumes = "application/json")
 public @ResponseBody String refreshModelParamRel(@RequestBody ParamWrapper pw) {
       System.out.println("params size"+pw.getParams().size());
 }
```

ParamWrapper:

```
public class ParamWrapper {

    private List<ParamDTO> params;
    private Integer modelId;

    public ParamWrapper() {
    }

    public List<ParamDTO> getParams() {
         return params;
    }

    public void setParams(List<ParamDTO> params) {
        this.params = params;
    }

    public Integer getModelId() {
        return modelId;
    }

    public void setModelId(Integer modelId) {
        this.modelId = modelId;
    }    
}
```

and my json:

```
  function addModelParams() {

    var paramWrapper = {};

    paramWrapper["modelId"] = selectedModelId;

    var params = {};
    var allParams = $("input[name='param']");
    for (i = 0; i < allParams.length; i++) {
        var param = {};
        param["id"] = allParams[i].value;
        param["checked"] = allParams[i].checked;
        params[i] = param;
    }

    paramWrapper["params"] = params;

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
        { 
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    }

    xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/ButelefonAPI/modelparams/refresh", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(paramWrapper));
}
```

in my sending json data seems everything is ok:

```
{"modelId":13,"params":{"0":{"id":"1","checked":false},"1":{"id":"2","checked":false},"2":{"id":"3","checked":false},"3":{"id":"4","checked":false},"4":{"id":"5","checked":false},"5":{"id":"6","checked":false},"6":{"id":"7","checked":false},"7":{"id":"9","checked":false},"8":{"id":"10","checked":false},"9":{"id":"11","checked":false},"10":{"id":"12","checked":false},"11":{"id":"13","checked":false},"12":{"id":"14","checked":false},"13":{"id":"15","checked":false},"14":{"id":"16","checked":false},"15":{"id":"17","checked":false},"16":{"id":"21","checked":false}}}
```

Comment: Can you post the error stack you got please?

Comment: Bad Request:The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

Comment: This seems to indicate problem with JSON, try logging the JSON, possibly by `alert(JSON.stringify(paramWrapper));`

Comment: I UPDATED QUESTION.PLEASE LOOK AT THE BOTTOM.I WROTE JSON REQUEST THERE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Ok then I think the syntax problem is with your `params = {}` object that should be an array `params = []` instead 
change:
    var paramWrapper = {};

```
var params = {};
var allParams = $("input[name='param']");
for (i = 0; i < allParams.length; i++) {
    var param = {};
    param["id"] = allParams[i].value;
    param["checked"] = allParams[i].checked;
    params[i] = param;
}
paramWrapper["params"] = params;
```

To this:

```
var paramWrapper = {};
var params = [];
var allParams = $("input[name='param']");
for (i = 0; i < allParams.length; i++) {
    var param = {};
    param["id"] = allParams[i].value;
    param["checked"] = allParams[i].checked;
    params[i] = param;//or params.push(param);
}
paramWrapper["params"] = params;
```

I think that should do it.

Comment: thanks for answer.i changed my method:

public @ResponseBody String refreshModelParamRel(@RequestBody ParamWrapper paramWrapper)


and json function:
var paramWrapper = {};
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(paramWrapper)); 

bu i get the same error.syntatically incorrect

Comment: Ok then take a look at my Edit.

Comment: Spring can handle and fill the object automatically.i wrote my all of services as like this method.And i declare as object not as String.i didn't parse any string in server side.Spring is parsing all of that and filling.
for example this method is working :
String updateModelParamRel(@RequestBody ModelParamRelDTO mpr)
and here i don't send mpr from json.whatever you send in ModelParamRelDTO structure Spring gets this json

but i don't know why i can't send list?

Comment: With the JsonObject and JsonArray you can use both objects and lists, but I think the problem is about formatting your Json object in javascript take a look at my EDIT.

Comment: thank you so much.so result is:

problem was just var params = []; not var params = {};
i tested without push it works.
and problem was not in server side whatever you wrote as parameter name it works:
#@RequestBody ParamWrapper pw;  or
#@RequestBody ParamWrapper paramWrapper;

and whatever your json array name is it works:
var paramWrapper = {};
or
var anythingYouWant = {};